# Jhipster - disable gulp tests on Prod package

Tags: gulp, jhipster

When I run a `mvn -Pprod package`, gulp runs tests.
But it fails during the tests. I don't know how  solve this for now.

So I would like to disable those tests.

How can I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

In `pom.xml`, remove the following from the prod profile's `build` tag:

```
<execution>
    <id>gulp test</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>gulp</goal>
    </goals>
    <phase>test</phase>
    <configuration>
        <arguments>test --no-notification</arguments>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

It's at line 750 in JHipster 3.3.0's `pom.xml`.

A much better solution would be to figure out why those tests are failing and fix them - their purpose is to help you find problems and they are failing for a reason.

Comment: Thanks bro, you save a life

Answer (score 0):

In newer JHipster version 5.7.2, to disable web tests (jest), you need to remove the following on pom.xml:

```
                    <execution>
                        <id>webpack build test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run webpack:test</arguments>
                            <npmInheritsProxyConfigFromMaven>false</npmInheritsProxyConfigFromMaven>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with mvn -Pprod package -DskipTests. -DskipTests should skip test during the build and package